# Two different join on same table Pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, pyspark

I have two dataframe df and buyers.
I need to apply two different type of join **inner** and **leftanti** on them and take 1% sample from leftanit and then do the union of these two resultant. I tried the below

```
buyr = df.join(buyers,on=['key'],how='inner')
non_buyr = df.join(buyers,on=['key'],how='leftanti')
onepct = non_buyr.sample(False,0.01,seed=100)
df_final = buyr.unionAll(onepct)
```

But due to this we have two stages for df and each stage of 731 partition take around 4hr to complete

[image]

Is there any way to perform the inner and left anti join in single step instead of two or any other efficient method to perform the same ?

Answer (score 0):

The Inner + Left anti is equal to a simple Left join.
Then, you can filter the line where `F.col("buyers.key").isNotNull()  # The inner` and `F.col("buyers.key").isNull()  # The left anti`.